# How to break from nested loops without using label's

Tags: java, for-loop, break

Hello here is my code.

```
int counter=0;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(++counter);
            if(counter==11)
                break;
        }
    }
```

My question is how to end both loops when counter is equal to 11 ?
In this example i just end the second loop. 
I know there is a way if i use label's, but is there any other way ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Super-ugly, but should work: `i = 5;` before `break;`

Comment: Use braces with @tobias_k 's answre.. both `i=5` and `break` should be executed.

Comment: @tobias_k could you write me code please ? Dont understand it..

Comment: Just saw your code @tobias_k thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer 1**

Well, you can do it like this by adding the condition into both for loops.

```
    for(int i=0;i<5 && counter!=11;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5 && counter!=11;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(++counter);
        }
    }
```

But you *are* violating the `DRY` principle and likely triggering an IDE / Sonar warning.

**Answer 2**

Add an exception to your class

```
private static class LoopDoneException extends Exception { }
```

Now throw it:

```
    try {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(++counter);
                if (counter == 11) {
                    throw new LoopDoneException();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (LoopDoneException e) {
        // expected
    }
}
```

**Answer 3**

On reflection, I think teh best approach is a `break` statement referring to the label `out`.

```
    out:
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("outer loop");
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println("inner loop: " + ++counter);
            if (counter == 11) {
                break out;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dang, same idea 3 seconds after you.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. Just got it what you were trying to say me. But there is not way to end both loops with break statement without using labels ?

Comment: Right Miljan, that is correct. Unless you want to throw an Exception, I can add that to my answer?

Comment: That would be very useful.

Comment: I don't like using exceptions to control logic, I would rather live with the anti-DRY repetition. Even in your example the DRY version is twice as many lines of code.

Comment: Fair enough. Personally I would just use a `break` label - pick your poison ;)

Comment: Seriously horrible misuse of exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Simply have a flag along with condition in outer loop, initially it was set to false. Once it meets your condition, just set the flag to true. so the outer for loop condition fails and gets out.

```
boolean isDone = false;
int counter=0;

for(int i=0;i<5 && !isDone; i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(++counter);

        if(counter==11){
            isDone = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really simple.. How i did not think of that.. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Your outer loop tests whether `i < 5`, so you could just invalidate that:

```
int counter=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        System.out.println(++counter);
        if (counter == 11) {
            i = 5; // this will end the outer loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, in practice I rather would not do this, but rather use the same condition again in the outer loop, or use a boolean flag. Readability counts!

Also, I think in this case, the use of labels would be perfectly fine and quite readable.

Comment: You could have `i = j = 5;` to break the inner loop as well.

Comment: Do you mean to use boolean flag as it was shown in sivakumar example ?
I totally forgot about boolean.. Thank you tobias very much..

Comment: I thought label's are bad for programming ? But i also agree that they are perfect in this case..

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't mind using labels to break loops, but if a style guide proscribes it, one option is to put the loop in its own method and return instead of breaking:

```
private void doNestedLoop() {
    for (/* outer stuff */) {
        for (/* inner stuff */) {
            if (/* outer should break? */) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can do

```
IntStream.range(0, 5)
         .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i * 5, i*5+5))
         .limit(11)  // instead of a counter
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

In Java 7 you can encapsulate it in a method

```
static void printOneToEleven() {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (++counter > 11)
                return;
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry.. I am learning from book which was written while java 7 was in use.. I never saw this before...

Comment: Do you think i should find book with Java 8 examples ?

Comment: @MiljanRakita I have read this book on Java 8 Lambdas and it is very good http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-8-Lambdas-Richard-Warburton/dp/1449370772

Comment: I am just a beginner do you think i should learn from books which are written in Java 8 or Java 7 could also work for me ?

Comment: @MiljanRakita I suggest you learn both.  You can't write Java 8 code only using Streams and Lambdas, but there is plenty of developers with more experience in Java 7 so knowing Java 8 is something which could help you.